# Hibernate.config.xml file error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

I am very new to Hibernate ,http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide
 I followed this link to create a Hibernate application,but i am getting th e following error: 
11:31:31,707  INFO [main] Environment:584 - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
11:31:31,738  INFO [main] Configuration:1423 - configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
11:31:31,738  INFO [main] Configuration:1400 - Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml

11:31:33,501  INFO [main] Configuration:553 - Reading mappings from resource : employee.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: employee.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1584)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at pack.storedata.main(storedata.java:13)

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>

   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
    root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>
   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

employee.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="pack.employee" table="emp1000">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <property name="firstName"></property>  
    <property name="lastName"></property>  

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

storedata.java:

```
package pack;

import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.Transaction;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  

public class storedata {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    //creating configuration object  
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  

    //creating seession factory object  
    SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  

    //creating session object  
    Session session=factory.openSession();  

    //creating transaction object  
    Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();  

    employee e1=new employee();  
    e1.setId(115);  
    e1.setFirstName("sonoo");  
    e1.setLastName("jaiswal");  

    session.persist(e1);//persisting the object  

    t.commit();//transaction is committed  
    session.close();  

    System.out.println("successfully saved");  

}  
}
```

employee.java:

```
package pack;


public class employee {  
private int id;  
private String firstName,lastName;  

public int getId() {  
  return id;  
}  
public void setId(int id) {  
  this.id = id;  
}  
public String getFirstName() {  
  return firstName;  
}  
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {  
  this.firstName = firstName;  
}  
public String getLastName() {  
  return lastName;  
}  
public void setLastName(String lastName) {  
  this.lastName = lastName;  
}  


}
```

Project Structure:

```
Hibernate
 ->src
   ->pack
     ->employee.java
     ->storedata.java
   -> employee.hbm.xml
   -> hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Comment: This is probably just a file path issue.

Comment: your hibernate.cfg is not able to find employee.hbm. may b path problem. where you have kept cfg and hbms?

Comment: I have edited my question,I have added my project structure .I have kept the cfg and hbms file under src folder

Comment: Try giving a full path for employee.hbm.xml and see if that's really your problem.

Comment: Yes ,I added the full path even then I am getting the same error .Edited path like : C:\java_workspace\firsthb\src\ employee.hbm.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put the hibernate.cfg.xml and employee.hbm.xml files inside resource folder.

```
<mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml/>
```

Else place hibernate.cfg.xml inside resource folder and place employee.hbm.xml with employee.java (model) in a separate package, then you need to give correct path name while mapping:

```
<mapping resource="pack.employee.hbm.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

just do the following changes
**in `hibernate.cfg.xml`-**

```
<mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>
```

and in
**StoreData.java** file

```
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear.

```
MappingNotFoundException: resource: employee.hbm.xml not found at
```

I think you have missed mapping of your xml file please try to check the required xml file, probably you have misspelled it.

example is working fine by the way in my machine

Comment: I have mapped my xml files properly and I have spelled the mapping file correctly .even then I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the opening tag

```
<hibernate-mapping>
```

in your employee.hbm.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav Gupta,But even then I am getting the same error

Comment: Can you please update your employee.hbm.xml adding <hibernate-mapping>